# VGA monitor won't detect on NVIDIA Quadro NVS 4200M

Tags: nvidia, vga

I am on a Dell Latitude E6420 and just installed 12.04. When I plug in my external monitor's VGA cable, the laptop doesn't detect any new monitor.

Here's the output of my lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation HDMI Audio stub (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (rev 34)
0b:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8221 (rev 05)
0b:00.1 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8231 (rev 03)
```

I tried installing the Quadro NVS 4200M from the nvidia website but got stuck in TTY after the installation finished.

Any ideas as to how I can get the external monitor to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong sorry! --

> You need to configure bumblebee drivers, your Nvidia runs on the
>   "optimus" platform which is not correctly supported by nvidia drivers.
>
> I suggest you to check the bumblebee project and this guide to
>   configure it on your laptop
>
> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: why bumblebee? bumblebee is for dual graphics card. The lspci shows there is only one vga card.

Comment: Woops sorry, you're right, wrong answer!